# Remove graph on inference

Tags: openvino

Unable to convert tensorflow to VINO format

Followed documentation

In case I wish to fix the graph using the Point 97 in the Mo_FAQ.html document in the VINO documentation docs,

which nodes do I include in  the first command -
python3 mo.py --input_model model/frozen_inference_graph.pb --tensorflow_subgraph_pattern ""FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/Relu6,..

Which of the nodes do I put above to offload a sub-graph of operations?

(Actual .pbtxt file had about 100 nodes)

Answer (score 0):

What model you are trying to convert? Not sure what you need to use param --tensorflow_subgraph_pattern to convert MobileNet, it supported out of the box.